# Prolog using append/3 predicate to redefine existing List

Tags: prolog

I have taken up a Prolog based AI course recently and am working on an Assignment to build a card game. My Predicates so far function to generate a list of Cards as a Deck of 52 and I am able to sucessfully query against said list.

The next step I am trying to implement if generating an initial Hand for 2 Players by drawing 5 cards from the shuffled Deck. For this I am using the nth1 function to select the first card in the Deck-List, then the select function to remove said card from the Deck and append to then write the card to the list that is considered the players hand.

this seems to work well, but where I am getting caught up is that i am using a loop to get more than just one card onto the players hand. To ensure the next run of the loop uses the new hand & deck states after the cards are drawn i then wanted to use append to define the previous Hand/ Deck as the New ones. But the Debugger seems to fail to run the Append, leading it to continuously override the players hand.

```
between(1,4,X),    % repeat card draw 4 times 
      getcard(CurrentDeck,CurrentHand,NewHand,NewDeck),   % Proceed to get a card feedign in the Current Deck and Hand, 
                                                   % then returning the New Hand and Deck
      append(NewDeck,[],CurrentDeck),           % Override previous Current Deck with New Deck
      append(NewHand,[],CurrentHand),           % Override previous Current Hand with New Hand
          write(Hand),nl.                       % Print Hand, for debugging and confirmation of operation
```

The getcard(X,Y,Z,A) function works as intended and I can see the correct values in the graphical debugger when tracing through the steps. But when returning and entering the append(NewDeck,[],CurrentDeck) line, the override does not occur, instead it returns back into the next loop of getcard and proceeds to override the current Hand the user has. The debugger also doesn't throw up an error to point me towards the cause of this issue.

I am using SWI-Prolog v8.4.3 for this coding exercise. Any ideas are welcome, maybe also suggestions on alternative solutions to my approach using append.

Comment: appending an *empty list* to another list is rather pointless. Can just use `=`

Comment: It fails on the use of X = Y or X is Y functions. That's why i tried to override the current List X by appending the New List Y into an empty list and trying to output it into the X Variable
``` 
append(Y,[],X). 
```
Should to my understanding make X take on the List Values of Y, instead it fails to do so and maintains it's current values on the repetition of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to mention, those 5 calls to `random_select` can be done more elegantly:

```
random_selects([], YsRest, YsRest).
random_selects([X|Xs], Ys, YsRest) :-
    random_select(X, Ys, Ys0),
    random_selects(Xs, Ys0, YsRest).
```

Call using:

```
random_selects(Hand, Deck0, DeckRest)
```

Comment: Note I opted for the simplest style in my answer, just to help Error42... if pursuing code compactness/elegance, I would opt for foldl instead of hand crafted loops

Comment: Both answers are very helpfull. This shortened soultion could allow me to figure out how to implement later draws of single cards as the routine progresses. But for ease of Troubleshooting and gaining an understanding for Prolog Programming I appreciate a long-hand version of code. I am still trying to grasp the basics, haven't even an idea of what the mentioned 'foldl' function would do. Thank you so much for your help @CapelliC & brebs

Answer (score 2):

Even more elegant:

```
?- initial_deck(Deck0), length(Hand, 5), foldl(random_select, Hand, Deck0, Deck).
```

Answer (score 1):

Prolog has a peculiar way to handle state, and - usually - is better to avoid to pursuit *state change*, and instead attempt to follow a *database style* programming. Not that this is always simple, or possible... specially when the computation must be coded in a cycle. For your use case, I would suggest to issue 5 times a [random_select](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=random_select/3)/3:

```
deck_hand(Deck0, Hand, DeckRest) :
  [C1,C2,C3,C4,C5]=Hand,
  random_select(C1,Deck0,Deck1),
  random_select(C2,Deck1,Deck2),
  random_select(C3,Deck2,Deck3),
  random_select(C4,Deck3,Deck4),
  random_select(C5,Deck4,DeckRest).
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, that solution appears to work. 
I do very much agree with your statement, it's very challenging to me to leave behind C/ Python style problem solutions and finding the way Prolog does it's own thing instead.